# atomic<UDT> aligning to word size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, alignment, atomic

I have a struct as follows:

```
#define _ENABLE_ATOMIC_ALIGNMENT_FIX

#ifdef _WIN32
    struct alignas(4) s {
        uint16_t a;
        uint16_t b;
        uint16_t c;
        uint8_t d;
        uint8_t e;
    };
#else
    struct alignas(8) s {
        uint16_t a; 
        uint16_t b;
        uint16_t c;
        uint8_t d;
        uint8_t e;
    };
#endif // _WIN32
```

This is supposed to be run on 64 bit linux machine so I am trying to build a struct of 64 bits which could be atomic and since it is of word size, it will be lock free. However, I am coding and testing this on a 32-bit windows computer. Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) always throws the following error:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(519): error C2719: '_Right': formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(525) : error C2719 : '_Right' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(542) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(548) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(580) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(587) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(594) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(602) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(610) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(617) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(624) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(632) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(640) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(647) : error C2719 : '_Value' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(680) : error C2719 : '_Val' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(686) : error C2719 : '_Right' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
2>C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\atomic(691) : error C2719 : '_Right' : formal parameter with requested alignment of 8 won't be aligned
```

I have tried using alignas(8) in windows and it still does not compile. I do not understand why the compiler is not able to align with the required fields. If I remove alignas tag, it gives the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up the error code on MSDN.  It's quite clear, alignment specifiers are not allowed on function parameters.  The calling convention does not allow this.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have used the alignment specifier on the struct not a function parameter. And I removed the alignas specifier and it still spits the same error (as specified in my question).

Comment: If removing `alignas(x)` gives the same error, then likely it is in other code different from what you posted.

Comment: @Ripi2 which other code?

Comment: You have not posted a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So I guess you do have more code.

Comment: @Ripi2 I have an entire project. But the error occurs when I try to use the above defined struct with the atomic library. Like std::atomic<s> temp;. Constructing this makes my code fail. Just wanted to post the relevant code.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes you are right. The error was coming not because I was using alignas() in my function parameters but because I was passing the above defined struct in the parameters.